# Git on Windows fileshare is SLOOOW compared to GitHub

Tags: windows, performance, git, samba

We decided to host our shared Git repositories on an internal Windows Server share. All devs then access this share via VPN connection, to push / pull changes.

And it works fine.

But we got suspicious that it was slower than normal, ie. compared to GitHub - so we decided to do a little speed test, and setup the same project both on the local fileshare and Github.

And the result was scary : Fileshare Git repository was 5-7 times slower than using GitHub.

Can anyone give me any clues to who there is the HUGE difference in speed ?

The Windows fileshare is located on a fair Windows Server 2003, which basically only servers as a fileserver and the server is NOT busy or anything like that.

All devs access this share from Mac OSX.

Answer (score 6):

If by "fileshare" you mean you are using the "[local protocol](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html)" (i.e. the remote repository is in another directory on a -- here *remote* -- disk), then this is normal: a SSH or smart http-based solution would be quicker.

> **The Cons**
>
> [...] If you want to push from your laptop when you’re at home, you have to mount the remote disk, which can be difficult and slow compared to network-based access.
>
> It’s also important to mention that **this isn’t necessarily the fastest option if you’re using a shared mount of some kind**.
> A local repository is fast only if you have fast access to the data.
> **A repository on NFS is often slower than the repository over SSH on the same server**, allowing Git to run off local disks on each system.

Since GitHub offers both access (SSH or smart HTTP), it will be quicker than a fileshare.

See [8 ways to share your Git repo](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#gitdaemon) for other ways to share your central repo.

Comment: Being a "Windows admin", and only having Windows servers in my company, I tried searching for possibilities to install a "Git server/deamon" in my Windows environment, but ended up using the shared folder solution. So no SSH or Smart HTTP for me.

Comment: Also, Mac OSX will be accessing windows based shares via samba, which will add some overhead

Comment: I once used the Cygwin ssh daemon (sorry, Windows service) to prove that you could get access to Windows git repos via ssh (see the cygrunsrv utility)

Comment: is it actually safe to do this? How does it safely lock files in case two people try to push at the same time?